# exception thrown on CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccspritebatchnode

I am attempting to create an animated sprite class, which has methods for starting and stoping the animation.  When I move my CCSprite variable from a local to an ivar, the class throws an exception.  With the CCSprite variable as a local, the class work, that is the sprite appears and is animated.

The project is ARC enabled, with all of the coocs2d files flagged with -fno-objc-arc. I used TexturePacker to create the underlying files, altho I don't think that has anything to do with the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

cocos2D version 2.01.00
Xcode Version 4.6.2

How the class is being called:

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *animatedSprite = [[AnimatedSprite alloc] init];
animatedSprite.position = ccp(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2);
[self addChild:animatedSprite];
```

class header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface AnimatedSprite : CCSpriteBatchNode
{
}

@end
```

class that works

```
#import "AnimatedSprite.h"

@interface AnimatedSprite()
{
    CCAction *action;
//    CCSprite *sprite;
}

@end

@implementation AnimatedSprite

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spriteSheet.plist"];
        self = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"spriteSheet.png"];

        NSMutableArray *animatedFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            [animatedFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sprite%d.png",i]]];
        }
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1.png"];
//        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1.png"];
        CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animatedFrames delay:0.1f];
        action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
        [sprite runAction:action];
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

class that throws an exception

```
#import "AnimatedSprite.h"

@interface AnimatedSprite()
{
    CCAction *action;
    CCSprite *sprite;
}

@end

@implementation AnimatedSprite

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spriteSheet.plist"];
        self = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"spriteSheet.png"];

        NSMutableArray *animatedFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            [animatedFrames addObject:
              [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sprite%d.png",i]]];
        }
//        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1.png"];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite1.png"];
        CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animatedFrames delay:0.1f];
        action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
        [sprite runAction:action];
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Stack trace

```
#0  0x01efc0ab in objc_release ()
#1  0x01efcbd9 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#2  0x024ae468 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#3  0x0156f8e4 in -[NSAutoreleasePool release] ()
#4  0x00abbc16 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#5  0x03214df9 in _PurpleEventCallback ()
#6  0x03214ad0 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#7  0x02481bf5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#8  0x02481962 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#9  0x024b2bb6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x024b1f44 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x024b1e1b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x00ab717a in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#13 0x00ab8ffc in UIApplicationMain ()
#14 0x000dcc66 in main at /iPhone Apps/Cocos/SpriteTest/SpriteTest/main.m:15
#15 0x000022b5 in start ()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to create a class that does sprite animation? There are many things out already that does this work for you. Look into [sprite and level helper.](http://www.gamedevhelper.com) They do animation automatically for you. There is no need to reinvent something that is already out for you :)

Comment: It is great that you gave him a link for some help. However, it is kind of rude not to answer the question. Giving alternative information is cool, but the reason he/she posted the question, was for an answer.